# How do I break out of the for loop inside an inner while loop

Tags: c++, arrays

For this loop, I need to be able to enter names into an array that has to be 100 elements long, and exit the array to read the names back once Q or q is entered, or the end of the array is reached. When I use this code, the program goes back to the beginning of the while loop without breaking the for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    while (true)
    {   
        cout << "Enter Player Name (Q to quit): ";
        getline(cin,playerName[i]); 
        if (playerName[i] == "Q" || playerName[i] == "q")
            break;
        cout << "Enter score for " << playerName[i] << ": "<< endl << endl;
    } 
}
```

Comment: It probably goes back to the beginning of the 'for' loop and drops back into the 'while' loop... How about a well-placed goto to exit both loops?

Comment: What is the purpose of the inner loop? As far as I can tell, it shouldn't be there at all. You only want to ask for input once per `i`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your description, it seems like the `while (true)` is completely redundant!!!

So you should simply do:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter Player Name (Q to quit): ";
    getline(cin,playerName[i]); 
    if (playerName[i] == "Q" || playerName[i] == "q")
        break;
    cout << "Enter score for " << playerName[i] << ": "<< endl << endl;
}
```

At this point, you can use `i` in order to tell how many names have been entered by the user.

Comment: You lead me to the correct answer. I am required to use a while loop per the pseudocode I have to follow for the assignment. I lost the for loop, and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the rare circumstances where a judicious `goto` may be the best available option.

```
for (...)
{
    while (...)
    {
        if (...)
            goto exit_loop;
    }
}
exit_loop:;
```

Some languages let you put a label on the `for` and use it in `break`, but C and C++ are not among them.  It can also make sense to extract the entire loop nest to its own function, allowing you to use `return` to exit both loops, but this may not work in context.

I personally think that this use of `goto` is easier to understand than a boolean + `if` in the outer loop, as suggested in other answers, but reasonable people can disagree about that.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your question correctly, then you don't need the while loop.  Without that while loop, break will exit the for loop, then you can enter a separate for loop (from 1 to 100) to print the contents of the array.

If the user enters less than 100 names at any point, then the second for loop will go from 1 to i, and output each array entry along the way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering the title - wrap both loops in a function:

```
void foo()
{
    for (;;)
        while (true)
            if (/* something */)
                return;
}
```

I otherwise agree with [barak manos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21800353/947836), you don't even need two loops.

Comment: +1 I would go with this, rather than the over-complex extra bools or the nasty goto thingies.

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean variable to tell you if the inner loop has broken:

```
bool broken = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    while (true)
    {   
        cout << "Enter Player Name (Q to quit): ";
        getline(cin,playerName[i]); 
        if (playerName[i] == "Q" || playerName[i] == "q") {
            broken = true;
            break;
        }
    }
        cout << "Enter score for " << playerName[i] << ": "<< endl << endl;
    } 
    if (broken) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a boolean variable to state that you breaked from the inner loop and then check it and break from the outer loop if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
bool done = false;
int i = 0;
for ( ; i < 100 && !done; i++ )
{
    cout << "Enter Player Name (Q to quit): ";
    getline(cin,playerName[i]); 

    if ( !( done =  playerName[i] == "Q" || playerName[i] == "q" ) )
    {
        cout << "Enter score for " << playerName[i] << ": "<< endl << endl;
        // some code for entering the score
    }
}
```

Take into account that you need to keep variable i that to know how many players were entered. So I defined i outside the loop.